# What do the symbols in the row header of DataGridView signify?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

The Windows Forms DataGridView automatically displays some symbols in the row header.

I cannot find any documentation of what symbols are displayed and exactly what they mean. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

(Sorry, this isn't really a programming question, and it's sounds like a shall-I-google-that-for-you type of question, but I have googled it and I can't find the answer.)

Comment: Active Row?  Editing?  New Row?

Comment: During editing it shows a triangle, an asterisk, a pencil. It might show more which I don't know about. Is there some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any documentation about the glyphs in [`DataGridViewRowHeaderCell`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.cs) but from the execution and source code it seems it uses these icons:

It uses these images: **Arrow**, **Pencil**, **Star**, **ArrowStar** and **Error**.

- **Arrow** is showing on header of current row.
- **Pencil** is showing when current cell is dirty. You can turn it off using `ShowEditingIcon` property.
- **Star** is showing on header of the new row.
- **ArrowStar** is showing on header of new row when new row is current row.
- **Error** is showing when the ErrorText of a row is set, Error can be also shown on cells with error. It can be shown near other glyphs or on a row without any glyph. You can control showing it using `ShowRowErrors` and `ShowCellErrors`

All images except error have RTL and LTR versions.